# Syntax errror message, on python idle

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

It say's there's a syntax error on my code, here is the new chunk I had added recently which must have an error somewhere. I am new to python, any help is much appreciated. Perhaps something with the indentation but I can't see where and it doesn't specify a line :(

```
def store_results(class_number, name, score):
   class_number = str(class_number) + ".txt" #this adds '.txt' to the end of the file (therefore creating a text file) so it can be used to create a file under the name of the class
   file = open(class_number, 'a') #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
   #file.write(str(students_names))
   file.write(str(name + " : ")) #writes the name and ":" to file
   file.write(str(score)) #writes the score to file
   file.write('\n')#writes the score to the file
   file.close()#safely closes the file to save the information

def store_results(class_number, name, score):
   class_file = "{}.txt".format(class_number)  # this adds '.txt' to the end of the file (therefore creating a text file) so it can be used to create a file under the name of the class
   with open(class_file, 'a') as f: # opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
      f.write("{}: {}\n".format(name, score)

def store_results(class_number, name, score): # this adds '.json' to the end of the file (therefore creating a json file)
   class_file = "{}.json".format(class_number) # first step: load the existing data
   if not os.path.exists(class_file):
      scores = {}
   else:
       with open(class_file, 'r') as f:
      scores = json.load(f)
      scores.setdefault(name, []).append(score)
      with open(class_file, 'w') as f:
      json.dump(scores, f)
```

The error message just says:

```
**SYNTAX ERROR: INVALID SYNTAX**
```

However the cursor jumps back to this line

```
def store_results(class_number, name, score):
```

Comment: Always post the full error message. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you, and you will get accurate answers faster.

Comment: Ok thank you, I had edited it with the error

Comment: add full error message (with line numer,etc.)

Comment: It doesn't specify the line number! That's why I am finding it extremely hard to identify :(

Comment: `f.write("{}: {}\n".format(name, score)` has a missing closing bracket.

Comment: run it without IDLE - maybe you get better error message.

Comment: Are you sure your code looks exactly like this? There's wrong indentation after last `else:`

Comment: btw: you have three functions with the same name - it can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you use format, you have:

```
f.write("{0}: {1}\n".format(name, score)
```

You are mission a closing parenthesis.

```
f.write("{0}: {1}\n".format(name, score))
```

That fixes the problem and the code goes trough the interpreter just fine. I would suggest using an IDE rather then simple idle, gives more insight on the problem and which line is happening, even though idle should told you as well.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was the error, along with a few others which I managed to fix as the error was more specific. I will accept the answer when It allows me (it says the answers been too soon)

Answer (score -1):

I think problem is because you have three functions with the same name - it is syntaxt error.

Comment: No that is not the case pyhton simple overrides the alredy defined symbol, in this case last defined would be called.

Comment: No it's not - it simply rebinds local name to newly created function. Bad practice? Yes. Syntax error? Nope.